# Proving two averages are asymptotically equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, summation, asymptotics

Suppose $f(n)\sim g(n)$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it necessarily true that \begin{equation}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|f(k+1)-f(k)|\sim\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|g(k+1)-g(k)|\end{equation}
as $n\to\infty$?

Intuitively this should be true; one would expect the average values of these differences to be asymptotically the same as the analogue for $g$, but I cannot figure out how to make this more rigorous. My idea was that, if the above is true, then it is also true that $\sum_{k=1}^n|f(k+1)-f(k)|\sim\sum_{k=1}^n|g(k+1)-g(k)|$ by multiplying through by $n$. But this doesn't really yield anything.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sim$ ? The difference tends to $0$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I believe the usual definition is that $F(x)\sim G(x)$ means that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=1$, but it would be useful to confirm that!

Answer (score 3):

Not true. With $f(n) = n$ and $g(n)=n +10(-1)^n$, then $f(n)\sim g(n)$ and
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|f(k+1)-f(k)|=1$$
while
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|g(k+1)-g(k)|=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left|20(-1)^{k+1}-1\right| \rightarrow  20 $$

Comment: Nice counterexample! I wonder if this is always the case that we cannot do this? What if we consider, for example, $\pi(x)$ to be the number of primes less than $x$. Would we be able to use $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$ to write $\sum_{k=1}^n|\pi(k+1)-\pi(k)|\sim\sum_{k=1}^N|\frac{N+1}{\log(N+1)}-\frac{N}{\log N}|$?

Comment: In general, think of $f$ and $g$ as being equivalent in magnitude, but with different oscillating derivatives/variations. That's where my example came from. You usually need stronger assumptions to control the variation rate. So I don't think you can do that with $\pi(x)$ either, at least without additional work.